# Tor: requesting a tor website

Tags: anonymity, tor

When you have a website that's hosted within the Tor network and one accesses this website with a Tor browser, does this person still use an exit-node ?

Or will this be an encrypted connection between the server and the client's browser?

(I'm talking about the Tor encryption that's used, so intermediary nodes can't decrypt traffic)

I want to know when surfing to a Tor website if traffic still passes through a random exit node ( like when not surfing to a tor website)  or not.

Any documentation on this is highly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All traffic happens within the TOR network, and there is no normal exit-node involved.

There is a node serving as rendevouz point, where your circuit, and the circuit of the hidden service meet. But the messages itself are end-to-end encrypted, so unlike an exit-node(used with an unencrypted protocol such as http), it can't listen in on your communication.

For a detailed description of how TOR hidden services work, check: [Tor: Hidden Service Protocol](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en)